# How to deal with execve function?

Tags: c, pointers, execve

I am writing this function:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char* hack[];
  hack[0] = "/bin/sh";
  hack[1] = NULL;

  execve(hack[0], &hack, &hack[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

my question is, what is the difference between writing the line:

```
execve(hack[0], &hack, &hack[1]);
```

instead of:

```
execve(hack[0], hack, NULL);
```

if there is any difference which is the best way? Writing the first type of expression I get a warning saying:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘execve’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
note: expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[3]’
```

what does this mean?

Comment: Side note: `char *hack[];` should be `char *hack[2];` (or better yet `char *hack[] = { "/bin/sh", NULL };`).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I will start with an explanation about `execve` to make it a bit clearer.

`execve` will run the program *pathname*, replacing the current process, stack frame and heap. For this it takes three arguments:

- The path of the program *pathname*. This is a basic `char*` with the path to your program.
- The arguments passed to your program *argv*. This has the same use as the `argv` passed to your own `main`: get command line arguments, with the first such argument being the `pathname` to the program.
- The environment variables *envp*. This lists the environment variables present in your program's execution context (for example $PATH which lists all the paths where your OS can reasonably find executable files).

Both *argv* and *envp* are `char **`, meaning they are lists of `char *` (null-terminated strings), with the last element being NULL.
A program can then expect to iterate them until they find a NULL pointer to gather its arguments and environment.

--

There are two differences between your two statements:

1. The second argument (argv):

   - In the first case, a **pointer** to the `hack` array, meaning you have a `char***`, not compatible with the declaration which expects a `char**`
   - In the second case, the `hack` array itself, which is a `char **` (AKA a string array)
2. The third argument (envp):

   - In the first case, a pointer to the second element of the `hack` array, which translates to "A string array whose first element is NULL".
   - In the second case, NULL, which **on LINUX systems** is interpreted like the above, but will cause an error in most other UNIX system.

To quote the execve(2) man page:

> On Linux, argv and envp can be specified as NULL.  In both cases,
> this has the same effect as specifying the argument as a pointer
> to a list containing a single null pointer. **Do not take
> advantage of this nonstandard and nonportable misfeature!**  On
> many other UNIX systems, specifying argv as NULL will result in
> an error (EFAULT).  Some other UNIX systems treat the envp==NULL
> case the same as Linux.

In conclusion, in your case, the proper call is

```
execve(hack[0], hack, &hack[1]);
```